# How does mhchem print its superscripts and subscripts?

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, mhchem

I need to replicate `mhchem`'s way of typesetting sub- and superscripts. It's different from what `$X^y$` and `$Z_w$` do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames, x11names, table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\rlap{$\mathrm{A}_2^+$}%
\textcolor{PineGreen}{\ce{A2+}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try again with `\rlap{${\mathrm{A}_2}^+$}` (Note the extra braces).

Comment: What are you up to? Maybe I can help even further than you ask for.

Comment: @mhchem I wanted to  to draw a structure with `chemfig` that was consistent with `mhchem`'s output. Inside a `\chemfig{}` all the content of `\ce{}` is considered a single "atom" (in `chemfig` terminology), so something like `\ce{A+}` would be too wide, having bonds pointing midway between the "A" and the plus sign. I resolved by defining two macros, `\newcommand{\pluscharge}{\rlap{$_{\phantom{i}}^+$}}` and an analogous for the minus sign, so `\chemfig{A\pluscharge-[:-90]B}` prints the atoms like `mhchem` would do and draws the structure correctly.

Comment: Late edit for the above: for better spacing and alignment it's better to define the macro as `\newcommand{\pluscharge}[1][]{\ensuremath{_{\vphantom{8}}^{#1+}}}` (this also takes the number of charges as an optional argument) and treat the sign as a separate atom: `\chemfig{A|\pluscharge-[:-90]B}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mhchem` places the index by itself without the superscript.  This way the index is not shifted down, as it doesn't need room for the descenders of a superscript.  The superscript is then applied to a seperate atom made up from the letter plus the index.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\rlap{${\mathrm{A}_2}^+$}%
\textcolor{green}{\ce{A2+}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the record, if one needs to write only a superscript, he has to fake the presence of a subscript higher than one ex, otherwise the superscript will be lower in math mode than inside `\ce{}`. E.g. I use `$\mathrm{A}_{\phantom{i}}^+$` (compare it with `\ce{A+}`)

Comment: That's a good approximation. mhchem's internals are a little bit more complex, because there are more cases than just a number as subscript and a positive charge as subscript. Most important, this solution would work only in math mode, but not with text fonts, im headings, TOCs or page headers.

Comment: @mhchem What do you suggest to use then?

Comment: If you do it by hand, everything is fine. You already figured out one special case, no subscript. There might be a few others, but you'll see. – But please use `\vphantom{8}` instead of `\phantom{i}`. It's better to use a number and you only need the vertical spacing.